# Does RTK Query compare the newly re-fetched data with the cached one to determine if there was a change?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

***NOTE:** I'm not trying to call the query hook in another component which should return cached data if the same arguments were passed to the hook avoiding a new request to be made, my issue is when forcing a refetch.*

I'm working on a React Native project and I'm having a small confusion regarding the inner workings of RTK Query when it comes to refetching fresh data and I can't seem to find an answer online.

I have a query that's getting triggered when the component mounts, and I have a `useEffect` that has the fetched data (which is an array of objects) in its dependencies array like so:

```js
    function MyComponent(props){
      ...
    
      const {
        data: teams,
        refetch,
      } = useGetUserTeamsQuery({userId}, {skip: !userId || !rolesToken});

      useEffect(()=>{
        if(teams){
          console.log("teams changed...")
        } 
      }, [teams])

    }
```

Now when the component first mounts I get `teams changed...` in the logs as expected, then when some event fires (socket reconnects) I call `refetch` to refetch fresh data in case the list of teams changed when the socket was disconnected, and the behavior I'm getting is:

After the refetch, my `useEffect` doesn't execute when I have the exact same result being returned from the server, which is confusing to me since I can see in my debugger that the request actually fires and goes from `pending` status to `fulfilled`, so normally I should be having a new reference to the array `teams` thus my `useEffect` should get triggered since the reference has changed even if the data is still the same.

Then when update the list of teams (adding the user to a new team for example) my `useEffect` executes and I get the log in the console.

**So my question is, does RTK Query perform some sort of comparison between the cached data and the newly fetched one to determine if the data has somehow changed and if the answer is no it would return the same reference ?**

Comment: What’s your cache key?

Comment: @DaveNewton it's `"getUserTeams({"userId":"some_user_id"})"`

Comment: Is the user ID changing between requests?

Comment: @DaveNewton No it's the exact same `userId` since the arguments aren't changing, I'm just triggering the refetch manually with the same args

Comment: That's what caching is: if the cache key matches it returns the cached data. Maybe I'm misreading your question.

Comment: @DaveNewton But I can see in my debugger the the request is actually firing, it's `pending` for a while then it becomes `fulfilled`, so I'm assuming there's new data being fetched ? Also from my understanding calling `refetch` would normally force a refetch regardless of the cache key I'm I wrong ?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean--you're correct, the refetch function should refetch the data. I'm not sure--IIRC by default RTK uses Immer so maybe there's some comparison logic in there? Not sure.

Comment: @DaveNewton Exactly that's my question, is there any comparison logic and if there is how does it work

Comment: If there is it'd work like you'd expect; a deep compare. Immer may do this automagically--you'd likely need to look at both the rtk-query code and possibly the Immer code if it isn't explicit in the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redux Tool Kit Query: Need same data in different two components but without duplicate requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73348227/redux-tool-kit-query-need-same-data-in-different-two-components-but-without-dup)

Comment: @Yilmaz Thanks for your comment but unfortunately it does not, in my case I'm not calling the query hook in a different component which should return the cached data if called with the same argument, but instead I'm forcing a refetch in the same component and somehow still getting the same result

Comment: @DaveNewton Haven't had the time to look into the code yet but I highly doubt they implemented a deep comparison since the shape of the returned data is unknown and could be absolutely anything and it would be a huge performance hit for large lists that contain deeply nested objects

Comment: @abdou-tech Must be magic then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if a new query will return the same data as the last query, you will get the same object back, to prevent unexpected (and unneccessary) rerender.

Even if a query will return partially equal data, that part of data will be kept stable.

Your `useEffect` here is a data synchronization mechanism - so unless data doesn't change, it will not reexecute. If this causes a problem with your logic, you are likely abusing `useEffect` for something it should not be used for, and should probably rethink the actual logic that you are applying.

---

There is a way of disabling this feature called structural sharing - but I stand by my statement that you should never rely on a `useEffect` like this.

The option can be added to your endpoint definition and is called `structuralSharing`, here is the docblock:

```js
  /**
   * Defaults to `true`.
   *
   * Most apps should leave this setting on. The only time it can be a performance issue
   * is if an API returns extremely large amounts of data (e.g. 10,000 rows per request) and
   * you're unable to paginate it.
   *
   * For details of how this works, please see the below. When it is set to `false`,
   * every request will cause subscribed components to rerender, even when the data has not changed.
   *
   * @see https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#copywithstructuralsharing
   */
  structuralSharing?: boolean
```

Comment: Is there some reference to that behavior in the docs?

Comment: @Terenfear No, but you can set an option per endpoint, I'll copy the text you get when hovering that option into the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @phry My intention by doing it this way inside a useEffect is that I needed to execute some logic each time my query is `fulfilled`, currently I cant' find any another way to do something like an `onQuerySuccess` type of thing unless I'm missing something, any suggestions?

Comment: @abdou-tech It seems like that should just not be of concern in your application. The point of a query is that you at some point have data in your application, so it is displayed. There should not be side effects from that - what if another component refetches that data. Should your side effect execute everytime? Most likely not. What does that effect do?

Comment: @phry In this example, I have a home component which is like that main component that contains the entire app's components as its children (so long as the user is authenticated) and where I manage a socket connection. As I said when the socket re-connects I needed to refetch the list of teams in case the list has changed when socket was off, after the refetch succeeds I needed to join the user to his new teams (if any exist) through the socket and that's what I did inside that useEffect.

Comment: @phry Now if a child component refetches the data, I would still have the same behavior since my home component is still mounted so the useEffect would still execute if the list of teams changes, meaning I will get a new reference to it then check if any teams were added/removed, then update the socket accordingly.

Comment: If this logic has nothing to do with your component (synchronizing with a websocket doesn't sound like it), you shouldn't do this in a component. You can use an endpoint lifecycle ([onQueryStarted](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted)) for this.

Comment: @phry Yes you're right if the component's state isn't affected we can do the logic inside `onQueryStarted` I didn't notice there was a `queryFulfilled` promise in there. What if the state of the component is affected? Like for example having to check the refetch results of two queries to make some third effect, or to update the component's state in some specific way, I guess there's nothing wrong in doing it inside a useEffect that has both results in its dependencies?

Comment: @abdou-tech You would never want to do that if no actual data changed, right?

Comment: @phry Yes, you are totally right. It kinda took me by surprise tbh it didn't seem intuitive to me that RTKQ has this behavior by default, I'm curious to know how does RTKQ determine if data has changed or not, in the docs it says: *preserving existing references if the values **appear** to be the same*, so what's the mechanism of comparision behind and how far should we rely on it? If for example the refetched list of teams has the exact same number of items but only some teamName changed, or teamMembers which is an array of userIds, would RTKQ detect such a change and return a new reference?

Comment: @abdou-tech It deeply compares all old values with all new values. If anything changes, it will return a new reference, but it will keep as much of the structure intact as possible.

Comment: @phry Thank you for all these insights, and for all the work you've been providing for the community, amazing library and amazing team :)